# Как сравнить элементы внутри двумерного списка (python)?

Tags: python

Есть допустим список a = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 2, 5], [6, 2, 5]]
a[0][1] == a[1][1] == a[2][1]

Пробовал так, но мне кажется, что это не самый лучший вариант:

```
for i in range(3):  
    for k in range(3):  
        if a[i][k] == a[i+1][k] == a[i+2][k]:  
            True
```

С обработкой исключения соответственно.

Comment: Какие элементы Вы хотите сравнивать? Каждый из элементов списка с другими элементами внутри списка/другого списка?

Comment: [Оно?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15855792/how-do-i-compare-2d-lists-for-equality-in-python)

Comment: @МихаилАлексеевич Хочу, чтобы первый элемент вложенного списка сравнивался с первым эл. другого вложенного списка, второй со вторым и т.д.

Comment: @socode К сожалению нет, там сравниваются конкретно списки, а мне надо сравнить элементы на одинаковых позициях, но в разных вложенных списках

Comment: Список списков фиксированного размера? :)

Comment: @МихаилАлексеевич да :)

Comment: Нормальный у вас вариант, как по мне. Только раз размер фиксированный, убрать цикл по i и оставить `if a[0][k] == a[1][k] == a[2][k]:`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> > > а мне надо сравнить элементы на одинаковых позициях, но в разных вложенных списках

```
from itertools import groupby

for nums in zip([1, 2, 3], [4, 2, 5], [6, 2, 5]):
    print(nums, len(list(groupby(nums))) == 1)
    # print(nums, nums.count(nums[0]) == len(nums))

# (1, 4, 6) False
# (2, 2, 2) True
# (3, 5, 5) False
```

Answer (score 2):

По-моему модуль Numpy идеально подходит для работы с N-мерными числовыми матрицами.

Пример:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 2, 5], [6, 2, 5]])
print(a)
```

Вывод:

```
[[1 2 3]
 [4 2 5]
 [6 2 5]]
```

Проверка:

сравниваем элемент по индексу `[0,1]` (1-я строка, 2-й столбец [вся нумерация начинается с нуля, поэтому `[0, 1]`]) со вторым столбцом: `[:, 1]`

```
In [7]: (a[0, 1] == a[:, 1]).all()
Out[7]: True
```

Как это работает:

```
In [8]: a[:, 1]
Out[8]: array([2, 2, 2])

In [10]: a[0, 1] == a[:, 1]
Out[10]: array([ True,  True,  True], dtype=bool)
```

для третьего столбца:

```
In [9]: (a[0, 2] == a[:, 2]).all()
Out[9]: False
```

---

Случай посложнее - пусть нам дана матрица:

```
In [64]: a
Out[64]:
array([[1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 6],
       [4, 2, 5, 0, 1, 7],
       [6, 2, 5, 0, 1, 8]], dtype=int64)
```

Надо найти все столбцы с одинаковыми элементами:

```
In [65]: (a == a[0,:]).all(axis=0)
Out[65]: array([False,  True, False,  True,  True, False], dtype=bool)

In [66]: a[:, (a == a[0,:]).all(axis=0)]
Out[66]:
array([[2, 0, 1],
       [2, 0, 1],
       [2, 0, 1]], dtype=int64)
```