# Не срабатывает if, elif python

Tags: python

Есть вот такой код (игра крестики-нолики):

```
for i in range(len(self.coubsfull)):
    for k in range(len(self.coubsfull)):
        try:
            if self.coubsfull[i][k] == self.coubsfull[i+1][k] == self.coubsfull[i+2][k] != 1:
                print('yes1')
                if self.coubsfull[i][k] == 'X':
                    player1.win = True
                else:
                    player2.win = True
                fig.drawline_vertical()
            elif self.coubsfull[i][k] == self.coubsfull[i][k+1] == self.coubsfull[i][k+2] != 1:
                print('yes2')
                if self.coubsfull[i][k+1] == 'X':
                    player1.win = True
                else:
                    player2.win = True
                fig.drawline_horizontal()
            elif self.coubsfull[i][k] == self.coubsfull[i+1][k+1] == self.coubsfull[i+2][k+2] != 1:
                fig.drawline_diagonal()
                if self.coubsfull[i][k] == 'X':
                    player1.win = True
                else:
                    player2.win = True
            elif self.coubsfull[i][k+2] == self.coubsfull[i+1][k+1] == self.coubsfull[i+2][k] != 1:
                fig.drawline_diagonal_reverse()
                if self.coubsfull[i][k+2] == 'X':
                    player1.win = True
                else:
                    player2.win = True
        except IndexError:
            True
```

Допустим,

```
self.coubsfull = [
    [1, 1, 'X'],
    ['X', 'X', 1],
    ['0', '0', '0']
]
```

(1 - пустые клетки)

При таком раскладке должен срабатывать второй условный блок, однако этого не происходит.

Задавал вопрос про обработку, предложили вариант сравнения через numpy, но я пока еще не пробовал.

[Как сравнить элементы внутри двумерного списка (python)?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/702053/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0-python)

Comment: при дебаге понял, что когда i = 2, то дальше первого условного блока программа "не уходит"

Answer (score 0):

Уже не актуально :)
Каждый условный блок добавил в try-except

Comment: Это очень плохо, так вы не научитесь нормально программировать